# Synology RS810+ PHP upgrade to 5.6

Tags: linux, ssh, php, nas, synology

I need to upgrade PHP from 5.5.33 to at least 5.6 in Synology RS810+ and the only way to do that is by manually swapping certain files via ssh (`cp` commands etc.).
But the main issue is that I have no idea which files I have to swap and where do I get the new ones.

I managed to install Ioncube through this method so I guess manual upgrade of PHP is possible:

[image: Terminal connection showing <code>php-v</code> and ioncube installed]